# Break lines after loading text from file and placing it in div nwjs

Tags: javascript, nwjs

After loading text from inside a file using `fs.readFileSync(Folder);`
How do I place it inside a div (which has contenteditable="true") in my nwjs app breaking lines according to how it was in the file?

Because a direct load places everything in the same line of that div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace all `\n` with `<br />`, or you can use the css style to preserve all line breakers:

```
<div style="white-space: pre-line">{your text}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Example of @MudOnTire's answer:

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
<div id="div"></div>
```

```js
var fs = window.nw.require('fs');
var path = window.nw.require('path');

var file = path.join(process.cwd(), 'folder', 'somefile.txt');
var data = fs.readFileSync(file);

data = String(data);
data = data.trim().split('\r\n').join('\n');
document.getElementById('pre').innerHTML = data;

var html = data.split('\n').join('<br>');
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = html;
```